# 2003 Honda CRV Part Identification

Tags: honda, radiator, leak, crv

Recently I have been having a coolant leak near the radiator.  Today the thermostat went all the way up and there was visible steam. Luckily I was near the house and able to park and turn the car off.

After taking off the bottom plastic, I was able to see that the leak was away from the radiator it self so it didn't appear to be a crack.

Looking in from the top down, I noticed something that didn't seem right (not a car person).

I pulled out the battery to get a closer look and for some photos. I touched the piece of rubber near this area and it fell right off.

It looks as if this part either pulled the rubber in or something came off of a pully/shaft? I could only assume this has something to do with pumping coolant to the radiator / engine?

Here is a link to the photos I took. Can some one confirm this doesn't look as it should and that it has something to do with the coolant?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

http://share.pho.to/ALg5B

Comment: Your pictures look like an engine mount. This keeps the engine and transmission from moving around too much and has nothing to do with cooling.

Comment: Make sure your coolant is at the right level so your engine doesn't overheat. Hurry up and find that leak. If it's away from the radiator, there are 2 likely places: the 2 big rubber hoses connected to the radiator, or the water pump. Hoses are cheap, water pumps are a bit more expensive but not terribly so.

Comment: To find your water pump, it will be near where all the belts are, it's one of the pulleys you have. Find the one that is connected to the radiator.

Comment: Gotcha, if it is the engine mount then I feel dumb. There was a little pooling of coolant right below this area so I assume it was coming from that. I will start the car in the morning when its light out and see if i can notice where the leak is coming from

Comment: Or maybe a subframe mount; what @tlhIngan said.   Not related.

Comment: :( appears to be - thanks for confirming I was way off haha

Comment: Also, you will **NOT** be able to see the water pump belt, as I am pretty sure on your '03 CRV has a tooth-side timing belt driven water pump.

Comment: So I know for sure this is coolant that is leaking, does this pass through the water pump?

Comment: @SBB Don't feel dumb. Engine mounts do look impressive. I've blamed stuff on them too until somebody pointed out what they were. You'll be disappointed when you see what your water pump really looks like. Yup, it's that tiny little thing. :)

Comment: http://oi63.tinypic.com/28tjj8k.jpg - It's a significant leak so I should be see where this is coming from now that I have the bottom plastic off. I just didn't start he car after removing it due to the false alarm above

Comment: @SBB Yes, the water pump moves the coolant through it's circuit of hoses. One of the radiator hoses should be leading you to it.

Comment: @SteveRacer is correct the water pump on the 2.4 or 3.5 is driven by the timing belt.

Comment: @SteveRacer - Here are some additional photos. Some of them are under the car where I could see the most wet areas but nothing really dripping at a constant pace. The top photos in here where I am pointing is where a big hose from the radiator is going back towards the engine. Once the thermostat hit high, I turned off the car and this hose closest to the engine was hissing and putting out steam. http://share.pho.to/ALoKi

Comment: This is near the middle of the car, I assume its the AC condensation being more active since the car is overheating. It's coming out a lot, not sure if that has anything to do with the root issue or a side effect of it trying to keep cool. https://youtu.be/N2tXcFrPgA8

Comment: @SteveRacer - Looks like the 2003 CRV has a timing chain vs a belt, I wonder if the pump hasn't been changed out since its typically done with a belt replacement

Answer (score 2):

That is the transmission mount:

[image]

[DEA PN: A4528; ANCHOR PN: 9433; WESTAR PN: EM9433]

If you turned the picture about 100° CCW, you'd see it will mount right up. While this DOES NOT have anything to do with your coolant leak, it is due for a change. The rubber is starting to crack on the inside. You will start feeling more and more vibration into your cabin, as well as jerky starting and stopping due to deflection which shouldn't be there.